# How to render multiple images, the one behind the other, without spaces?

Tags: c#, wpf, viewport3d

Let's say I have an image like : [image: black hole]

And I want to make it look like a cylinder in my Viewport3D.

What I'm doing is rendering the image n times, modifying the position of my mesh n times by a very small value. But even doing this, I can clearly see the slices. I could try to reduce the value again and render more images, but I think the way I'm doing it might be wrong, and this would take a lot of time to load.

Any advice?